# Javascript Slider not working on website after installing other script

Tags: javascript, slider

I am working on Magento eCommerce site and I am running into a problem after installing a color swatch plugin. The problem appears in the thumbnail views on the product page. What exactly is happening is, when you click the down or up arrow to scroll the thumbnails, after so many clicks, the slider will get stuck and replay the slides in the same position for at least 4-5 clicks, and then it will resume, but get stuck again once it does a full loop of the images. It was functioning 100% perfectly prior to installing the color swatch plugin. I looked in FireBug but I didn't really see any obvious errors, but I am still learning how to use the tool and could have made a mistake.

Here is the URL: http://modernego.info/index.php/spring-dress.html
Here is the URL to the template I purchased in its original stat (with the working slider): http://demo.emthemes.com/manwear/index.php/briefs/reprehenderit-voluptate-8.html

Does anyone have any ideas on how I can work this out? I've tried for over 10 hours trying to fix this doing various methods, trying to duplicate other files, etc.

I would greatly appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think its not because of script errors, its because of events handling, i've the same situation earlier, i've used jQuery slider, it worked perfectly on normal page but when i placed it in a floating div then its mouse event wouldn't detached

then i've handled mouse event and changed as per mouse movements...

you may debug your page by events... i think some other events causing this problem..